# woocommerce cart item remove ajax not working in hosted site

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Cart removing ajax not working properly(item remove from cart but page not refresh) when site host (cpanel).But same function working in local.Can someone explain the reason for it.

**Hosted site console**

[image: Hosted site console]

**Local site console**

[image]

Comment: The status code `500 Internal Server Error` suggests there might be some sort of error in your code. Enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` in your `wp-config.php` file, run the ajax action again and see the `/wp-content/error.log` what might be the issue.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen thank you very much for your response.